# How to put dates on the top column of my output in R

Tags: r

I have three columns of data

```
Category Date Value
A 10/12/2018 1
A 10/14/2018 2
B 10/12/2018 3
B 10/13/2018 4
C 10/12/2018 5
C 10/14/2018 6
```

How can I transform my output so that the output has dates on the top like this and groups the Categories?

```
   10/12/2018 10/13/2018 10/14/2018
A     1                      2
B     3           4
C     5                      6
```

I've tried searching for crosstab and some basic R functions and appreciate your thoughts on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is called "wide" format. There are many package and methods in R that do this kind or formatting. Bing Sun, pointed to the `dplyr` method. I prefer the `data.table` method.

```
## loading your data here
library(readr)
x <- read_delim("Category Date Value
A 10/12/2018 1
A 10/14/2018 2
B 10/12/2018 3
B 10/13/2018 4
C 10/12/2018 5
C 10/14/2018 6", delim = " ")

## casting your data to wide format
library(data.table)
xcast <- dcast(x, Category~Date, value.var = "Value")
xcast
```

returns...

```
  Category 10/12/2018 10/13/2018 10/14/2018
1 A         1         NA          2
2 B         3          4         NA
3 C         5         NA          6
```

Comment: This was helpful.  For my real-life scenario I am now using dcast from dplyr with the same syntax, and using the "fun.aggregate = sum" to sum up quantities by date.                x_sum_wide <- dcast(x, Category ~ Date, fun.aggregate = sum, value.var = "Value")

Answer (score 1):

This is a reshape problem.

```
library(tidyr)

df %>% spread(Date,Value)

  Category 10/12/2018 10/13/2018 10/14/2018
1        A          1         NA          2
2        B          3          4         NA
3        C          5         NA          6
```

Comment: It would be helpful to add `library(tidyr); library(dplyr)` to the top of this answer.